# Update Button Property from Custom Class

Tags: swift

I have a UIButton which inherits from a custom class `ColorButton`.

```
@IBDesignable
class ColorButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable
    var buttonColor: UIColor?


    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
        buttonColor?.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }

}
```

I'm able to initially set the button's color, but when I try to change it using the following method, nothing changes.

```
myButton.buttonColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

I believe I'm just updated the property, but I need to redraw the button to see the new color. I'm unsure on the best way to do this.

Comment: I think you should override buttonColor property in ColorButton class as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have only property that do nothing when you set it. You need to set `backgroundColor` parrent class property ( this is property of `UIButton` in your case) to solve this problem:

```
@IBDesignable
class ColorButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable
    var buttonColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return self.buttonColor
        }
        set {
            self.backgroundColor = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

But in your example you don't need to create custom class for it. You can call `backgroundColor` from ordinary `UIButton` object if you wand get only this functionality

Comment: yes your right. i just ended up using the backgroundColor of the regular UIButton class and drawing a circle using that. it now updates correctly. thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code,and use it in my demo. It worked fine when i change "buttonColor" in IB.So it seems when you change "buttonColor" in code,you have to redraw your Button:

```
var buttonColor: UIColor?{
    didSet{
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```